# ClickHouse: Materialized view is not be timely optimized to merge the partitions

Tags: clickhouse

I created a table and two materialized views recursively.

Table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `log_details` (
  date String, 
  event_time DateTime, 
  username String, 
  city String) 
ENGINE = MergeTree() 
ORDER BY (date, event_time) 
PARTITION BY date TTL event_time + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

Materialized views:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `log_u_c_day_mv` 
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY date 
ORDER BY (date, username, city) 
AS 
SELECT date, username, city, count() as times 
FROM `log_details` 
GROUP BY date, username, city
```

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `log_u_day_mv` 
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree() 
PARTITION BY date 
ORDER BY (date, username) 
AS 
SELECT date, username, SUM(times) as total_times 
FROM `.inner.log_u_c_day_mv` 
GROUP BY date, username
```

Insert into log_details →　Insert into log_u_c_day_mv → Insert into log_u_day_mv.

`log_u_day_mv` is not be optimized after 15 minutes inserting `log_u_c_day_mv` even over one day.

I tried to optimize `log_u_day_mv` manually and it works.

```sql
OPTIMIZE TABLE `.inner.log_u_day_mv` PARTITION 20210110
```

But ClickHouse does not timely optimize it.
How to solve it?

Comment: consider using [FINAL](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from/#select-from-final)-modifier in FROM-clause.

Comment: @vladimir Materialized view cannot have PREWHERE, SAMPLE or FINAL..

Comment: @vladimir Thank you. I understand your suggestion. Use FINAL in SELECT query. But it doesn't optimize the MV to perform a scheduled merge in background.

Answer (score 1):

Data always is not fully aggregated/collapsed in MT.

If you do `optimize final` the next insert into creates a new part.

CH does not merge parts by time. Merge scheduler selects parts by own algorithm based on the current node workload / number of parts / size of parts.

**SummingMT MUST BE QUERIED with sum / groupby ALWAYS.**

```
select sum(times), username
from log_u_day_mv
group by username
```

**DO NOT USE** `from log_u_day_mv FINAL` it reads excessive columns!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank Denny. I will notice the query with aggregated functions and groupby.